# convert camera position

Tags: opengl, matrix, camera

I have a function from an external lib which takes the following camera parameters:

- x,y,z coordinates for "center of
  orbit"
- x,y,z vector from "center of orbit"
  to "camera direction"
- orbital radius
- camera roll

How can I calculate these parameters from the ones I got:

- position vector
- view vector
- zoom min/max
- rotation angle
- decline angle of the camera

?

And on a related subject: what's a 'camera roll' anyway? Is there somewhere a picture explaining this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x,y,z coordinates for "center of orbit"

- I guess this is up to you, let's call it "centerOrbit"

orbital radius

- orbitalRadius = Length(cameraPos - centerOrbit)

x,y,z vector from "center of orbit" to "camera direction"

- (cameraPos - centerOrbit) / orbitalRadius

camera roll

- this could be your "decline angle of the camera" (just guessing again)
- for explanation of what is a camera roll, try googling "yaw pitch roll"